# how do i prove (mathematical proof) that $\alpha$ is not an integer for the list of conditions below

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Say we have $4$ numbers with the following relations:\begin{align}
& (a,b,c,n)\in\mathbb{N} \\[10pt]
\text{where } & c>a>b>0 \\[10pt]
\text{and } & c^{n-1}<a^{n-1}+b^{n-1} \\[10pt]
\text{and } & n>14
\end{align}

show that if $$0<\alpha<b^{n-1},\alpha=\frac{(c-a)a^{n-1}+(c-b)b^{n-1}}{c}$$

then $\alpha$  is not an integer

Comment: @amWhy i'm begener in math, this how i learn by the correction of like yours ... thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. If you read the guidelines to post, you will see that you are strongly encouraged to add your thoughts and attempts as part of your post. Otherwise, users might think that you are lazy and just want us to do your work for you and so will vote to close. Inspire us by showing us your work and get us to help you!

Comment: Do not vandalize your post, abdallah, nor repost under a different account and username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any proof is prevented by the following 
**Counter-example:** For 
$$ a=32, b=31, c=33, n=15,$$
we have
$$ \alpha = \frac{(33-32)\cdot 32^{14}+(33-31)\cdot 31^{14}}{33}=81650893671484968002\in\Bbb N$$

and verify

$$ c=33 > a=32 > b=31 >0$$
$$ 0<\alpha = 81650893671484968002<b^{n-1}=1180591620717411303424$$
$$ c^{n-1}=1816331681783800622529<a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}=1937535555938207623745$$
$$ n=15>14$$